# Pass serialized object created in R to Python, then unserializing the object in python script

Tags: python, r, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am using Azure Machine Learning, and I would like to pass a binary file created in R script to Python script, to process it further in python.

To pass the binary file created in R, I serialized the data.
But how can I unserialize data in python script to recover the original data?

The R code is below

```
serialized <- as.integer(serialize(data,NULL))
dataset <- data.frame(serialized,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
maml.mapOutputPort("dataset");
```

Comment: ... this is presumably some language-dependant binary serialization format. Python doesn't know about that format, and unless someone has written a library in Python to understand that format (doubtful that this could be general), you'll have to write your own way. Or use another serialization format.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using DataFrames, you might try Feather. It was made by the guy that made Pandas :)

https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/03/29/feather/

Otherwise, you can read a binary file in Python withe the 'rb' setting:

`f = open("myfile", "rb")`

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, I think it's not necessary to connect the R output with the Python input via serialization on Azure ML. You can try to use the `Convert to CSV` module to connect them, as the figure below.

[image]

The code in `Execute R Script` is as below.

```
dataset <- data.frame(data,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
maml.mapOutputPort("dataset");
```

Then the output `dataset` will be converted to CSV and be imported into the Python Pandas DataFrame as input `dataframe1`.

Hope it helps.